# Cant resize UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, com, add-in, vbide

I am trying to write a simple extension for VBIDE. My problem is that the UserControl (WinForm) does not stretch to the width of the dockable window and does not resize when the window is resized.

This is ToolWindow with control:
[image]

Control.Designer.cs:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.commandLineBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
    this.resultLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.resultToolTip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // commandLineBox
    // 
    this.commandLineBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
    this.commandLineBox.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
    this.commandLineBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.commandLineBox.Name = "commandLineBox";
    this.commandLineBox.TabIndex = 0;
    this.commandLineBox.Text = "";
    this.commandLineBox.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.commandLineBox_Enter);
    this.commandLineBox.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.commandLineBox_KeyDown);
    // 
    // resultLabel
    // 
    this.resultLabel.AutoSize = true;
    this.resultLabel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
    this.resultLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 38);
    this.resultLabel.Name = "resultLabel";
    this.resultLabel.TabIndex = 1;
    this.resultLabel.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.resultLabel_TextChanged);
    // 
    // Terminal
    // 
    this.Controls.Add(this.resultLabel);
    this.Controls.Add(this.commandLineBox);
    this.Name = "Terminal";
    this.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

I'm trying to change `control.Dock` to `DockStyle.Fill` in the `Extension` class after displaying the window, but `control = null`:

[image]

```
    public class Extension : IDTExtensibility2
    {
        private VBEWrapper _wrapper;
        private VB.AddIn _addin;
        private VB.Window terminalWindow;
        public void OnConnection(object Application, ext_ConnectMode ConnectMode, object AddInInst, ref Array custom)
        {
            _wrapper = VBEWrapper.GetInstance((VB.VBE)Application);
            _addin = (VB.AddIn)AddInInst;
            
            switch (ConnectMode)
            {   
                case ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_AfterStartup:
                    CreateWindow();
                    break;
                case ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void CreateWindow()
        {
            Termin control = null;
            try
            {
                terminalWindow = _wrapper.VBE.Windows.CreateToolWindow(
                            _addin,
                            "VBATerminal.Terminal",
                            "Terminal",
                            "EE7EEC61-E607-44B8-830F-34839672CD30",
                             control);
                terminalWindow.Visible = true;
                const int defaultWidth = 350;
                const int defaultHeight = 200;

                if (terminalWindow.Width < defaultWidth)
                {
                    terminalWindow.Width = defaultWidth;
                }

                if (terminalWindow.Height < defaultHeight)
                {
                    terminalWindow.Height = defaultHeight;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
//
    }
}
```

### **EDIT:**

Here's a variant that should (I guess) assign a value to control, but it doesn't do that either:

```
object control = null
terminalWindow = _wrapper.VBE.Windows.CreateToolWindow(
            _addin,
            "VBATerminal.Terminal",
            "terminal",
            "EE7EEC61-E607-44B8-830F-34839672CD30",
             ref control);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you assign a value to the control variable? I don't know what this `CreateToolWindow` function does, but this method of passing argument cannot assign any value to the variable.

Comment: You're right. Here's a variant that should (I guess) assign a value to control, but it doesn't do that either:
```
object control = null
terminalWindow = _wrapper.VBE.Windows.CreateToolWindow(
            _addin,
            "VBATerminal.Terminal",
            { "terminal",
            "EE7EEC61-E607-44B8-830F-34839672CD30",
             ref control);
```

Comment: Is control still null? As I said I don't know what this `CreateToolWindow` function does, maybe the author made the same mistake.

Comment: yes, control = null after the function is executed. Here is the documentation on it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtoolwindow-method

Comment: I mean your code shows that is a wrapper, the return value may be ignored by mistake.

Comment: The wrapper acts as a Singleton for the current vbe instance. This is necessary for further interaction with this class. At this level, the error is excluded. I am sure of this, as I first tried without the wrapper and the result was the same.